# phoenix jdbc doesn't work, no exceptions and stuck

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, hbase, apache-phoenix

I'm new to phoenix and hbase.hbase table and phoenix view works well and i can fetch data through phoenix. when I access jdbc to phoenix,it stucks.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
public class Phoenix {
    private static String driver = "org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        System.out.println("start...");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:phoenix:[my_cloud_server_ip]:2181");
        System.out.println(con);
        con.close();
    }
}
```

(only one zookeeper server has public internet ip,so i write this ip there,does it matters?)

it prints "start..." and no response any more

BUT when when the url is  "jdbc:phoenix:ip:2181" or  "jdbc:phoenix:ip:2181/hbase"

i got no response

when i add some other words ,for example "jdbc:phoenix:ip:2181/balabala"

i got NULL POINTER EXCEPTION

why ?

I hope u can understand what i say:)

Answer (score 1):

Reproducing your example, I am getting a `java.net.SocketTimeoutException` after 60 seconds, caused by `java.net.UnknownHostException: unknown host: <hostname_of_my_zk_server>`. But maybe that's what you called "no response" if you were in a hurry (or if you have a custom `hbase-site.xml` with a larger timeout client-side).

This error seems like the one explained in [this article](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/how-use-apache-phoenix-jdbc-driver-run-reports-hbase) (section Zookeeper at the end) :

> As in our case CDH was running in a test VM, we encountered this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18428722/hbase-java-client-unknown-host-localhost-localdomain
>
> That was worked around by adding localhost.localdomain to the existing /etc/hosts entry for cluster1, which was already pointing to the right IP address.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18477804/7804058) on SO summarizes the solution.

Basically, you need to add an entry to your `/etc/hosts` client-side :

```
<my_cloud_server_ip> <hostname_of_my_cloud_server_ip>
```

Moreover, you need to have an `hbase-site.xml` client-side (you can use the one on your server as a basis).

Comment: thank you very much!! i changed my JDBC jar and use "jdbc:phoenix:thin:url="(actually i don't know whats difference). and it works.i will have a try use your solution.thank you again.