# Spark 2.2.0 unable to connect to Phoenix 4.11.0 version in loading the table to DF

Tags: pyspark, hbase, apache-phoenix

I'm using the below techstack and trying to connect Phoenix tables using PySpark code. I have downloaded the following jars from the url  and tried executing the below code. In logs the connection to hbase is established but the console is stuck with out doing nothing. Please let me know if anybody encountered and fixed similar issue.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.phoenix/phoenix-spark/4.11.0-HBase-1.2

jars:
phoenix-spark-4.11.0-HBase-1.2.jar
phoenix-client.jar

Tech Stack all running in same host:

Apache Spark 2.2.0 Version

Hbase 1.2 Version

Phoenix 4.11.0 Version

Copied the hbase-site.xml in the folder path /spark/conf/hbase-site.xml.

Command executed ->

usr/local/spark> spark-submit phoenix.py --jars /usr/local/spark/jars/phoenix-spark-4.11.0-HBase-1.2.jar --jars /usr/local/spark/jars/phoenix-client.jar

Phoenix.py:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("pysparkPhoenixLoad").setMaster("local")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

df = sqlContext.read.format("org.apache.phoenix.spark").option("table", 
"schema.table1").option("zkUrl", "localhost:2181").load()
df.show()
```

Error log: Hbase Connection is established, however in the console it is stuck and timing out error is thrown

18/07/30 12:28:15 WARN HBaseConfiguration: Config option "hbase.regionserver.lease.period" is deprecated. Instead, use "hbase.client.scanner.timeout.period"

18/07/30 12:28:54 INFO RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=10, retries=35, started=38367 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=row 'SYSTEM:CATALOG,,' on table 'hbase:meta' at region=hbase:meta,,1.1588230740, hostname=master01,16020,1532591192223, seqNum=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at these answers :

- [phoenix jdbc doesn't work, no exceptions and stuck](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51571626)
- [HBase Java client - unknown host: localhost.localdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18477804)

Both of the issues happened in Java (with JDBC), but it looks like it's a similar issue here.

Try to add ZooKeeper hostname (`master01`, as I see in the error message) to your `/etc/hosts` :

```
127.0.0.1    master01
```

if you are running all your stack locally.

Comment: thank you for the response, the zookeeper is already set and up locally. hosts file points with the right IP. I'm able to run Spark-Hive ORC pyspark programs. I'm trying alternative by connecting directly to hbase , however this time its different  issue.

Comment: earlier comment is incomplete pls follow - it is unable to find org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase class even after we download the required jars spark-hbase-connector_2.10-1.0.3.jar and run the command spark-shell --jars /usr/local/spark/jars/spark-hbase-connector_2.10-1.0.3.jar --conf "spark.executor.extraClassPath=/usr/local/spark/jars/spark-hbase-connector_2.10-1.0.3.jar"

Comment: If you want to do this in Python as in your first example, you can read [this post on connecting directly Spark and HBase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38470114/how-to-connect-hbase-and-spark-using-python). I think you will encounter the same issues : the timeout you got seems related to the way Spark connect to HBase cluster. But it's worth to try.

Comment: Thank you again for sharing the links. I tried the same steps for the Hbase connection on pyspark but the error message is so simple "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase Java.Noclass found" exception. I checked the class availability in the JARs path. Not sure if the JAR is able to map or not some one mentioned the python 2.7 may not support some latest scala JARs to run in python wrapper. I'll start around all from beginning in another server.

Comment: Hi, I found the issue is for 2 reason: You're right norbj, the zookeeper hostname I have been giving as ip addr instead of hostname and the second one is the sparkdriver and executor class path needs to be set explicitly using the -conf parameter whenever we submit the program even though i placed them inside the spark-detault.conf.